# how do i apply cool effect to above code?

Tags: mouseover, effect

i am going to  apply cool effect to top of this site http://neshanteam.ir

```html
<div class="item item-small item-lightblue"> <!-- three -->
  
    <div class="img-thumb" style="background-image:url(images/content/300/3.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="content">
     <div class="content-alignment">
      <h5> 4 نکات مهم در زنده نگه داشتن وب سایت</h5>
      <a href="http://neshanteam.ir/default.aspx?page=post&amp;postid=1026"> <h3 style="direction:rtl;">  4 نکته مهم  استراتژیک در بروز رسانی سایت </h3> </a>
     
     </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

how do i apply cool effect to above code ?